# How to extract the index of a value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is the scenario:

I have the following variables:

```
val = [('am', '<f8'), ('fr', '<f8')] # val is type numpy.recarray     

am = [12.33, 1.22, 5.43, 15.23]  # am is type numpy.ndarray  

fr = [0.11, 1.23, 2.01, 1.01]   # fr is type numpy.ndarray
```

What I need is to detect the index for `am = 12.33` and `am = 15.23`, once extracted (in this case indexes are `[0]` and `[3]`), I need to create the new variables:

```
new_am = [12.33, 15.23] 

new_fr = [0.11, 1.01]
```

My question is: Any idea about how to extract the indexes?

I have already used `.index` and `np.where` but it seems to have problems since I received an error message for `.index`:

```
"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute ".index"
```

and for `np.where` the returning index is nothing `array([], dtype=int64)`

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: So you want the index as `np.array([0, 3])` here? `np.where(am == 12.33)[0]` doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: Correct, and with that...produce the "new_am" and "new_fr" represented above.

Comment: no...`np.where(am == 12.33)[0]` return an empty array

Comment: Make sure `am` and `fr` are `numpy` array before hand.

Answer (score 3):

You may want the `np.in1d` which returns an array of boolean to indicate if an element is in another array:

```
import numpy as np
am = np.array([12.33, 1.22, 5.43, 15.23]) 
fr = np.array([0.11, 1.23, 2.01, 1.01])

index = np.where(np.in1d(am, [12.33, 15.23]))[0]
index
# array([0, 3])

am[index]
# array([ 12.33,  15.23])

fr[index]
# array([ 0.11,  1.01])
```

---

Or maybe you have an array with attributes:

```
new_arr = np.array(zip(am, fr), dtype=val)

index = np.where(np.in1d(new_arr['am'], [12.33, 15.23]))[0]

new_am = new_arr[index]['am']
new_fr = new_arr[index]['fr']

new_am
# array([ 12.33,  15.23])

new_fr
# array([ 0.11,  1.01])
```

Comment: Thanks! interesting....seems to work for the values I gave you, but not for my real case values...all of them have exactly the same features of the values from the example above: `>>params['ampl'] ---> array([ 3931.41287385, 412.51629703, 257.47891338, ..., 193.89134605, 192.66807322, 192.20132863]) ---> index = np.where(np.in1d(params['ampl'], [3931.41287385]))[0] ---> index ---> array([], dtype=int64) `

Comment: That could be due to the float number inaccuracy. You can test this by `params['ampl'][0] == 3931.41287385` to seem if they are equal. Some tolerance has to be introduced here.

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately same behavior `index = np.where(params['ampl'][0] == 3931.41287385) ---> index ---> (array([], dtype=int64),) `

Comment: No, I mean literally `print(params['ampl'][0] == 3931.41287385)`, you will see that it should be true but it returns false due to float number inaccuracy.

Comment: Thanks Psidom for your help! You were right, that was a inaccuracy in the float number, I used `np.around` to reduce the number to 3 decimals and worked perfect!